# Max distance between 0s in matrix - double loop

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix which only consists of 0s and 1s. I want to make a nested loop which checks the consecutive 0s in my matrix and prints out the number as the distance . I will use the distance later to compute distance beetween points of the matrix.

Here's my code and my test matrix B.

```
B = [ 1     1     1     0     0     0     1
 0     0     0     1     1     1     1];


for i=1:2    
  for j=1:7    
    if B(i,j)==0   
        jtemp=j;  
        distance=0;  
        while B(i,jtemp)==0  
            jtemp=jtemp+1;  
            distance=distance+1;  
        end
        fprintf('%0.0f,The distance is\n',distance)
    end
  end
end
```

When I run this code I get something like this :

3,The distance is
2,The distance is
1,The distance is
3,The distance is
2,The distance is
1,The distance is

So my question is why this code doesn't print the distance by calculating the consecutive 0s in a row of the matrix

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The question is why it doesn't work properly , for example  in the first row it doesn't come with the answer the distance is 3

Comment: You can do this much more simply with `diff` and `find`.

Comment: Your `fprintf` command seems malformed.  Try this instead: `fprintf('The distance is %g\n',distance)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is due to the successive calls of `j` (from 1 to 7, whatever the value of jtemp is). You may insert a condition (`if j<jtemp`) that tells matlab not to process further (`continue`) until `j` matches `jtemp` again.

```
for i=1:2

    jtemp = 1;

    for j=1:7

        if j<jtemp
            continue
        end
```